# Want to make a slideshow using ImageView and a For Loop

Tags: android, imageview, slideshow

I want to change the image of an Image view using a for loop, a String array and the png images in drawable folder.One Image should rest for 5 seconds then the next should appear.Here is the code I used.And it's not working properly.The images are not changing.It waits 5 seconds per each loop but the images are not changing.At last the last image is loaded.Please someone help me...

```
 private String [] array1 = {"card2c","card2d","card2h","card2s",
                                    "card3c","card3d","card3h","card3s",
                                    "card4c","card4d","card4h","card4s",
                                    "card5c","card5d","card5h","card5s",
                                    "card6c","card6d","card6h","card6s",
                                    "card7c","card7d","card7h","card7s",
                                    "card8c","card8d","card8h","card8s",
                                    "card9c","card9d","card9h","card9s",
                                    "card10c","card10d","card10h","card10s",
                                    "cardjc","cardjd","cardjh","cardjs",
                                    "cardqc","cardqd","cardqh","cardqs",
                                    "cardkc","cardkd","cardkh","cardks",
                                    "cardac","cardad","cardah","cardas",};

for(int j=0;j<52;j++)
{
   int resID_temp1 = getResources().getIdentifier(array1[j] , "drawable", getPackageName());
   Drawable image_temp1 = getResources().getDrawable(resID_temp1);
   Player1.setImageDrawable(image_temp1);  // Player1 is the ImageView

   try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
       }
  catch(InterruptedException ex)
    {
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

}
```

Tried the Timer

```
(for(int j=0;j<52;j++)
{
   timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
     @Override
    public void run() {
    //switch image here
    int resID_temp1 = getResources().getIdentifier(array1[j] , "drawable", getPackageName());
    Drawable image_temp1 = getResources().getDrawable(resID_temp1);
    Player1.setImageDrawable(image_temp1);
    }
}, 0, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using timers instead:

```
//Declare final variable here

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
@Override
public void run() {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Switch (declared final) image variable here
        }
    });

  }
}, 0, 5000);
```

Something like that... I am not by my computer though.

Concepts: runOnUithread and final variables might also be of interest to read about. final is because otherwise the variable cant be manipulated on another thread (actually Its only another scope really here). RunOnUiThread is because graphical components must only be manipulated on the main UI thread, although the TimerTask is run on another separate thread.

Comment: for(int j=0;j<52;j++)
{
   timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
 public void run() {
 //switch image here
 int resID_temp1 = getResources().getIdentifier(array1[j] , "drawable", getPackageName());
 Drawable image_temp1 = getResources().getDrawable(resID_temp1);
 Player1.setImageDrawable(image_temp1);
 }
}, 0, 5000);

Comment: I tried the timer and I have updated my question..But it doesn't allow me to use non final variables inside the timer..

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code example, you're changing the image resource, but then immediately sleeping the same thread that changed the image resource which will block it and prevent the image from visibly changing (particularly bad if this is the UI thread as this will lock up your app).

You should do as JohnyTex suggests and use a TimerTask to change the image every 5 seconds which does not require sleeping and so will not block the current thread.